How to recognise linebreaks in longtable with \smash?
Following the advice received in my previous question, I am using \smash to achieve aesthetic vertical spacing in my longtable.
However, this has the effect of causing linebreaks to be unrecognised, as shown here:

How do I fix this such that the linebreak is recognised? At least the one between the last row of the previous 'block' and the first row of the next one.
Note: I know that I can make manual adjustments with vspace and whatnot, but that's not an option here because this page is just 1 out of hundreds that I'm auto-generating. I use a Python script to write and compile the .tex file.
MWE:
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}  %% sans serif base
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=0.5in,top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For prettier tables
\usepackage{siunitx} % For aligning numbers by decimal point
\usepackage{longtable} % For tables that span multiple pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\usepackage{array} % For advanced table features

% proper bold casing in siunitx
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}
    
% siunitx setup
\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=0,
    group-separator={,},
    group-minimum-digits=4, % groups digits by thousands
    input-ignore={,},
    detect-all,
    detect-weight=true,
    detect-inline-weight=math,
    tight-spacing=true,
    table-number-alignment = right % Align numbers to the right
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Agency – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE TITLE}\\[0.1in]
    Officer – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE NAME}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
        @{}p{1cm}  % Column for 'Butiran' with fixed width
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1cm}   % Column for 'Program / Aktiviti' left-aligned
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}   % Column for 'Program / Aktiviti' left-aligned
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}  % Column for OA / OS center-aligned
        S[table-format=11.0]
        S[table-format=11.0]
        S[table-format=6.0]
        S[table-format=6.0]@{}
    }
    \toprule
    \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header}\\ \textbf{Header}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024} }} \\ \\
    \midrule
    \\
    \endfirsthead
    
    \toprule
    \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header}\\ \textbf{Header}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024} }} \\ \\
    \midrule
    \\
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

\bfseries 000000 & \multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}}{\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright \bfseries A Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title (QWERTYUIOP)}}} & & 416930000 & \B 429940000 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 10000 & 199615000 & \B 207984200 & 3123.0 & \bfseries 3123.0 \\* \\*
& & & 20000 & 188065400 & \B 205758600 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 30000 & 27536900 & \B 14142000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 40000 & 1390700 & \B 1786200 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 50000 & 322000 & \B 269000 & &  \\ \\ \\ 

& 000000 & {\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright A Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title}}}  & & 36000000 & \B 33415200 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 10000 & 18170000 & \B 18174200 & 233.0 & \B 233.0 \\* \\*
& & & 20000 & 15045400 & \B 13630000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 30000 & 1964900 & \B 346000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 40000 & 619700 & \B 1100000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 50000 & 200000 & \B 165000 & &  \\ \\ \\ 

& 000000 & {\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright A Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title}}}  & & 36000000 & \B 33415200 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 50000 & 200000 & \B 165000 & &  \\ \\ \\ 

& 000000 & {\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright A Much Much Much Much Much  Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much  Much Much Much Much MuchLonger Proper-Cased Title}}}  & & 36000000 & \B 33415200 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 50000 & 200000 & \B 165000 & &  \\ \\ \\ 

\end{longtable}

    
\end{document}


Use multirow (as already suggested by @David in a comment to your other question) and/or add an extra empty table row. Or use tabularray (as already suggested by @samcarter in a comment to the same question) \smash is intended to hide the depth of the box. So the result is expected.

@cabohah As flagged by others in response to that suggestion - tabularray takes very long to compile. I know this result is expected with \smash, but it does seem to be the best solution to the previous problem, as multirow throws the general alignment off.

the line breaks are recognised. just the depth of the box containing the line breaks is set to zero. so there's nothing to fix in terms of line breaks. to fix the problem you either have to add vertical space in to compensate for the depth of the box or you have to not set the depth to zero in the first place. probably better to try fixing whatever alignment issues you had with multirow if tabularray or similar isn't an option. (and I do know it can ramp up compilation time e.g. it's easy for people to exceed overleaf limits.)

@cfr I think my best bet is probably to use Python to script something checking the length of text in that cell, and add an appropriate number of linebreaks. Slightly hacky, but at least it's dynamic!

If you have a problem using multirow, you should show that problem. Currently it is unclear, why you think you cannot use it.

As suggest @cabohah in his answer, you should try to use lomngtblr of tabularray table (it is not entirely clear, if you realyx need long table, your MWE doesn't contain any information about table captionand table continuation).
With longtblr code for your table is much shorter and clear:
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}  %% sans serif base
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin=0.5in,vmargin=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Agency – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE TITLE}\\[0.1in]
    Officer – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE NAME}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{tabularray} % For tables that span multiple pages
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx} % For prettier tables
% proper bold casing in siunitx
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}


\begin{document}
    \begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{default}{}  
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{} 
\sisetup{group-separator={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4,
         drop-zero-decimal,
         detect-weight=true,
         }
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     % <---
    label=none,     % <---
                ]{width=0.9\textwidth,      % if the table needs to be narrower than the width of the text
                  colspec = {@{} Q[l, font=\bfseries]
                                 Q[l, wd=11mm]
                                 X[l, cmd=\linespread{0.82}\relax]
                                 c
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=9.0}]
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=9.0}]  
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=4.0}] 
                                 Q[c, si={table-format=4.0}]  @{}},
                hspan=minimal,
                row{1} = {guard, font=\bfseries, c, m},
                rowhead = 1,
                }
Header  &   \SetCell[c=2]{}    Header  
            &   &   {Header\\ Header}
                    &   {Header\\ 2023}
                        &   {Header\\ 2024}
                            &   {Header\\ 2023}
                                &   {Header\\ 2024} \\ 
    \midrule
000000  &   \SetCell[c=2]{}    A Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title (QWERTYUIOP) 
            &   &   & 416 930 000 
                        &\B 429 940 000   
                            &   &                   \\*
        \cmidrule{5-6}
        &   &   & 10000 
                    & 199 615 000 
                        &\B 207984200 
                            & 3123.0 
                                &\B 3123.0      \\*
        &   &   & 20000 
                    & 188 065 400 
                        &\B 205758600 
                            &   &               \\*
        &   &   & 30000 
                    & 27536900 
                        &\B 14142000 
                            &   &               \\*
        &   &   & 40000 
                    & 1390700 
                        &\B 1786200 
                            &   &               \\*
        &   &   & 50000 
                    & 322000 
                        &\B 269000 
                            &   &               \\
    \addlinespace[3ex]
    & 000000 
        &   A Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title
            &   & 36000000 
                    &\B 33415200 
                        &   &                   \\*
        \cmidrule{5-6}
        &   &   & 10000 
                    & 18170000 
                        &\B 18174200 
                            & 233.0
                                &\B 233.0       \\*
        & & & 20000 & 15045400 &\B 13630000 & &  \\*
        & & & 30000 & 1964900  &\B 346000   & &  \\*
        & & & 40000 & 619700   &\B 1100000  & &  \\*
        & & & 50000 & 200000   &\B 165000   & &  \\
    \addlinespace[3ex]
        & 000000 
            &   A Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title
                & & 36000000 
                    &\B 33415200 
                        &   &                   \\*
        \cmidrule{5-6}
        &   &   & 50000 
                    & 200000 
                        &\B 165000 
                            &   &               \\
    \addlinespace[3ex]
        & 000000 
            &   A Much Much Much Much Much  Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much  Much Much Much Much MuchLonger Proper-Cased Title
                &   & 36000000 
                    &\B 33415200 
                        &   &                   \\*
        \cmidrule{5-6}
    &   &   & 50000 
                & 200000 
                    &\B 165000 
                        &   &                   \\   
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \endgroup    
\end{document}



I'm trying to avoid the bulked up space this creates between the numbers @Zarko - that was the reason for implementing the smash in the first place (with reference to this).

@Thev, than stick with @cabohah suggestion. It is up to you what you like to have. In my solution, as should be evident, \smash is not needed for almost the same result (to my opinion, my code gives pretties), however, code is much simpler, clear and shorter, need only one compilation for final result (what with longtable is not the case). However, it has drawback to you: learn to use new package. Regarding to benefits is worth to invest small effort to learn it (it is not so much different from longtable.

It's to long for a comment, but shouldn't be an answer, so please don't vote for it!
It's just an example of using multirow. Maybe you can use it to explain your “alignment problem”:
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}  %% sans serif base
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=0.5in,top=0.8in,bottom=0.8in}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For prettier tables
\usepackage{siunitx} % For aligning numbers by decimal point
\usepackage{longtable} % For tables that span multiple pages
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % For custom headers and footers
\usepackage{array} % For advanced table features
\usepackage{multirow}

% proper bold casing in siunitx
\newrobustcmd\B{\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}\bfseries}
    
% siunitx setup
\sisetup{
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=0,
    group-separator={,},
    group-minimum-digits=4, % groups digits by thousands
    input-ignore={,},
    detect-all,
    detect-weight=true,
    detect-inline-weight=math,
    tight-spacing=true,
    table-number-alignment = right % Align numbers to the right
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{Agency – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE TITLE}\\[0.1in]
    Officer – \textbf{AN UPPERCASE NAME}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
        @{}p{1cm}  % Column for 'Butiran' with fixed width
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1cm}   % Column for 'Program / Aktiviti' left-aligned
        >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}   % Column for 'Program / Aktiviti' left-aligned
        >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}  % Column for OA / OS center-aligned
        S[table-format=11.0]
        S[table-format=11.0]
        S[table-format=6.0]
        S[table-format=6.0]@{}
    }
    \toprule
    \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header}\\ \textbf{Header}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024} }} \\ \\
    \midrule
    \\
    \endfirsthead
    
    \toprule
    \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Header}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header}\\ \textbf{Header}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2023}}} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack[c]{\textbf{Header} \\ \textbf{2024} }} \\ \\
    \midrule
    \\
    \endhead
    
    \midrule
    \endfoot
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot

\bfseries 000000 & \multicolumn{2}{p{4cm}}{\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright \bfseries A Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title (QWERTYUIOP)}}} & & 416930000 & \B 429940000 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 10000 & 199615000 & \B 207984200 & 3123.0 & \bfseries 3123.0 \\* \\*
& & & 20000 & 188065400 & \B 205758600 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 30000 & 27536900 & \B 14142000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 40000 & 1390700 & \B 1786200 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 50000 & 322000 & \B 269000 & &  \\ \\ \\ 

& 000000 & {\smash{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright A Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title}}}  & & 36000000 & \B 33415200 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 10000 & 18170000 & \B 18174200 & 233.0 & \B 233.0 \\* \\*
& & & 20000 & 15045400 & \B 13630000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 30000 & 1964900 & \B 346000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 40000 & 619700 & \B 1100000 & &  \\* \\*
& & & 50000 & 200000 & \B 165000 & &  \\ \\ \\ 

& 000000 & \multirow[t]{7}{=}{A Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Longer Proper-Cased Title}  & & 36000000 & \B 33415200 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 50000 & 200000 & \B 165000 & &  \\* \\* \\* \\* \\

& 000000 & \multirow[t]{7}{=}{A Much Much Much Much Much  Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much Much  Much Much Much Much MuchLonger Proper-Cased Title}  & & 36000000 & \B 33415200 & & \\*[0.07in] \cline{5-6} \\*
& & & 50000 & 200000 & \B 165000 & &  \\* \\* \\* \\* \\* \\

\end{longtable}

    
\end{document}


For a real solution I would still suggest tabularray. Yes, I know, tabularray is slower than standard tabulars, but this is the cost for such a multi-talent that is able to handle several cases including cell merging with colors.

The issue is that you're manually inserting the linebreaks required to make this work - I need to dynamically generate this content.
